# Is $\lfloor -x \rfloor$ the same as $-(1+\lfloor x \rfloor)$?

Tags: functions

Provided $x$ is a  positive real, does $\lfloor -x \rfloor = -\left(1+\lfloor x \rfloor\right)$ ?

If not, is there a relation between relation between $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\lfloor-x\rfloor$?

Comment: Have you tried this for a few cases like $x=1.25$. What do you conclude?

Comment: It works when I take examples, but is there any proof?

Comment: When you are doing calculations, don't forget about $x=17$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two types of cases to consider: $x$ is integer and $x$ is non-integer. Your equation works for the latter case, but fails for the former, so it is not valid.

The equation that does hold is $\lfloor -x\rfloor=-\lceil x\rceil$. Note that whever $x$ is non-integer one has $\lceil x\rceil=\lfloor x\rfloor+1$, so you get the equation you wrote for that case, as I mentioned.

Comment: So my equations is right provided x is a positive non integer?

Comment: It looks that way, so try to prove it!

Comment: @Niharika: "positive" is irrelevant, since $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is well behaved with respect to shifts by integers (i.e., $\lfloor x+n\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+n$ whenever $n\in\Bbb Z$), unlike the silly "truncate towards zero" operation that is often built into computer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if $x=0$ then $\lfloor -x\rfloor=0$ and $-(1+\lfloor x\rfloor) = -1.$

In general, it isn't possible to express $\lfloor -x\rfloor$ as a continuous function of $\lfloor x\rfloor$, because $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is upper semi-continuous, but $\lfloor -x\rfloor$ isn't.

Comment: Actually it isn't possible to express $\lfloor -x\rfloor$ as a function of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ _at all_, since $\lfloor -0.5\rfloor\neq\lfloor0\rfloor$ while $\lfloor 0.5\rfloor=\lfloor0\rfloor$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Good point! My reasoning becomes more useful if we want an even stronger result: $\lfloor -x\rfloor$ isn't a continuous function of $\lfloor g(x)\rfloor$ where $g$ is a continuous, increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way to analyse these kinds of questions. Write $x$ in the form $x=\lfloor x \rfloor + \{ x \}$, where $\{x\}$ is the "fractional part" of $x$, satisfying $0\leq \{x\}<1$, and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the "integer part" of $x$.

What can we then say about $-x$? Well:

$$ -x =  -\lfloor x \rfloor -\{x\} = (-\lfloor x \rfloor -1) + (1-\{x\}).$$

Now, it seems clear from here that the integer part of $-x$ is $(-\lfloor x \rfloor-1)$, and the fractional part of $-x$ is $1-\{x\}$. However there is one caveat. Since $0\leq \{x\} <1$, then $0<1-\{x\}\leq1$, and in the case where $1-\{x\}=1$, then it does not constitute that fractional part of $-x$ any more.

For this reason, there are actually two cases to look at.

**Case 1:** $\{x\}=0$, *i.e.* $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Then $x$ is an integer, and $\lfloor -x \rfloor=-x=-\lfloor x \rfloor$.

**Case 2:** $0<\{x\}<1$.

Using our analysis from before, $0<1-\{x\}<1$, and $-x=(-\lfloor x \rfloor -1) + (1-\{x\})$. Since $(-\lfloor x \rfloor -1)$ is an integer, it follows that

$$\lfloor -x \rfloor = (-\lfloor x \rfloor -1) = -(\lfloor x \rfloor +1)$$

in this case.